# Php Newbie, echo not working?

Tags: php, echo

So this is almost definitely a newbie question, but I'm going through the w3 tutorial on php and on my server I can only get echo to work sometimes.

For example in one trial they have me submitting inputs in one form and picking them up in another, and echo works in that case, but in this code it won't:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>
This should work!! <?php
$str = "Hello, World!";
echo $str; 
?>
It failed...
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The output should just be: `This should work!! Hello, World! It failed...` But instead it just returns `This should work!! It failed...`, to the html page when I look at it.

Any ideas on how I could possibly get this to work?

Comment: what's the output? nothing or the raw code?

Comment: file should be named .php. if it's .html it will not output anything.

Comment: I feel dumb. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you have forgotten to let the filename end with `.php`.

So everything between the `<(?php)` and the `(?)>` is interpreted as a html tag and not visible. See your raw html output, then you may notice what's going on.

Comment: Yeah this solved it. Thank you it was a just a simple new learner mistake!