# simple PHP echo not working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to learn basics of **php**.So I tried following example as in [http://www.w3schools.com/](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_var1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>A Header</h1>
<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code was working two days ago. But now PHP part doesn't work.I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253891/php-newbie-echo-not-working) thread,but It is not that problem. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: are you running it via a web server with PHP enabled?

Comment: What does "PHP part doesn't work" mean? Do you see the PHP tags in the HTML source or nothing at all?

Comment: also, I suggest using a better resource to learn PHP than w3schools; there are many places on the web that will give you better advice.

Comment: I am simply running it on browser from local hard drive.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work. You need a web server.

Comment: you need to install xampp or wamp or lamp in your machine...

Comment: You can't run a server side language (php) without a server to interpret the server side commands. In bare basic terms, the browser only reads out the text sent to it from the server.

Comment: There are too many possible causes for this. Please **add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue** that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Possibly your wamp server has not completely started is the icon in green colour for wamp server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you start learning PHP using this website http://www.developphp.com/list_php.php#Getting_Started_with_PHP_Programming it has everything you need to get you started, tutorials are nice and easy to follow :)

Check the Installation section and then maybe have a look at this one http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=194 to solve your problem.

Hope it helps!- Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your web-server can execute php-scripts. Go through this: http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Comment: I tried (http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php) tutorial  too it prints only **Hello World
'; ?>**

Comment: Giv the code you tried

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>